# How can I filter whether a list contains the param?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can I filter whether a list contains the param?

In my Django-Rest-Framework project, I list the physical_server:

```
  [
    {
        "id": 23,
        "name": 'A1'
        "ipv4s": [
            {
                "id": 313,
                "ip": "43.243.33.33",
                "netmask": "255.255.255.248",
                "prefix": 29,
                "is_gateway": false,
                "is_network_ip": false,
                "is_broadcast_ip": false,
                "desc": null,
                "ctime": "2018-04-26T21:17:34.868492+08:00",
                "uptime": "2018-05-21T12:09:25.674283+08:00",
       ....
```

this is my list API view :

```
class PhysicalServerListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PhysicalServerListSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    pagination_class = CommonPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_params = self.request.query_params

        ip_address = ''
        try:
            ip_address = query_params.pop('ip_address')  # this maybe `43.243.33.33`
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        qs = PhysicalServer.objects.filter(xxxx)  # there I want the ip_address filtered if it in the `ipv4s`.

        return qs
```

How can I realize this filter?  because it is not the physicalserver's property. I can not use `filter(name='xxx')` to do that.

---

**EDIT-1**

I know I can use the for-loop to iterate the queryset's ipv4s, but I am not sure whether this is convenient or efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter server by related model's field use `__` [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) notation:

```
ip_address = query_params.pop('ip_address')
qs = PhysicalServer.objects.filter(ipv4s__ip=ip_address)
```

To make server's `ipv4s` list contains only filtered ip use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
qs = PhysicalServer.objects.filter(ipv4s__ip=ip_address).prefetch_related(Prefetch('ipv4s', queryset=IPV4S.objects.filter(ip=ip_address))
```

Now server's `ipv4s` will show only filtered ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

How abount filter like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query_params = self.request.query_params
    ip_address = ''
    try:
        ip_address = query_params.pop('ip_address')  
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    qs = PhysicalServer.objects.all()  
    if ip_address:
        qs = [p for p in qs if ip_address in [d['ip'] for d in p['ipv4s']]]
    return qs
```